# Linking PHP with Android Studio to get Firebase Tokens

Tags: php, android, firebase, mysqli

Can someone help me understand this piece of code. Thanks in advance.What is the purpose of OKHttpClient? Is there any alternative for this block of code?

```
private void registerToken(String token) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("Token",token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("notify.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use loopj library for api call. it is very simple .Follow the steps for Android. Add dependency in your gradle

```
 compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Request your web Api

```
 String url="Your url here";
  RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

        requestParams.put("Token", userToken);
    new AsyncHttpClient().post(url,requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          String rs = new String(responseBody);



        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
```